# Quadratic Extensions of an element g

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, galois-extensions

Let $K= \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ be the cyclotomic field of the $p^{th}$ roots of unity for an odd prime $p$. Let $g = \sum_{n=0}^{p-1} \omega^{n^2}.$ Here $\omega$ denote a primtive $p^{th}$ root of $1.$ I want to show that [$\mathbb{Q}(g): \mathbb{Q}] =2.$ I spent last 30 hours on this problem, but I don't see any progress. The good thing is that using this result, I could prove some cool facts about $g.$ Please note that the problem might require the definition of Lagrange resolvents.

The following is the definition of Lagrange resolvents. Let $K$ be any cyclic extension of degree $n$ over a field $F$ of characteristics not dividing $n$, and which contains the $n^{th}$ root of $1.$ Let $\sigma$ be a generator of the cyclic group Gal$(K/F).$ Then for $\alpha \in K, $ and any $n^{th}$ root of unity $\zeta$, the Lagrange resolvent $(\alpha, \zeta) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \zeta^{j} \sigma^{j}(\alpha).$ By the way, this is an exercise from Dummit and Foote.Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Galois group of $\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q$ consists of maps $\sigma_a$ for
$1\le a\le p-1$ characterised by $\sigma_a(\omega)=\omega^a$. Can you show that
(i) $\sigma_a(g)=g$ when $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, 
(ii) $\sigma_a(g)=-g$ when $a$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $p$?

Comment: Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you prove (i) $g\notin\Bbb Q$, (ii) $g^2\in\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Thank you so much. Please allow me some time to check. I will let you know.

Comment: From (ii), it's clear that  $g \notin \mathbb{Q}.$

Comment: I need to show that $g^2$ is fixed by any automorphism $\sigma_{a}.$

Comment: Yes, I did it. Thanks so much.